# Extract all paths within href from html using Nifi

Tags: html, apache-nifi

I want to extract all paths within href from the HTML page using Nifi.

below is the HTML content.

```html
<html><head><title>nemweb.com.au - /Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/</title></head><body><H1>nemweb.com.au - /Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/</H1><hr>

<pre><A HREF="/Reports/Current/">[To Parent Directory]</A><br><br>    Monday, February 11, 2019  4:31 PM        &lt;dir&gt; <A HREF="/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/DUPLICATE/">DUPLICATE</A><br>        Sunday, June 26, 2022 10:30 PM        16031 <A HREF="/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262235_0000000365889273.zip">PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262235_0000000365889273.zip</A><br>        Sunday, June 26, 2022 10:35 PM        15958 <A HREF="/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262240_0000000365889453.zip">PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262240_0000000365889453.zip</A><br>        Sunday, June 26, 2022 10:40 PM        16049 <A HREF="/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262245_0000000365889621.zip">PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262245_0000000365889621.zip</A><br>        Sunday, June 26, 2022 10:45 PM        16012 <A HREF="/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262250_0000000365889822.zip">PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262250_0000000365889822.zip</A><br>        Sunday, June 26, 2022 10:50 PM        15980 <A HREF="/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262255_0000000365889975.zip">PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262255_0000000365889975.zip</A><br>        Sunday, June 26, 2022 10:55 PM        15990 <A HREF="/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262300_0000000365890155.zip">PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262300_0000000365890155.zip</A><br>        Sunday, June 26, 2022 11:00 PM        16031 <A HREF="/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262305_0000000365890351.zip">PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262305_0000000365890351.zip</A><br>
```

I want the output below format only

/Reports/Current/
/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/DUPLICATE/
/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262235_0000000365889273.zip
/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262240_0000000365889453.zip
/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262245_0000000365889621.zip
/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262250_0000000365889822.zip
/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262255_0000000365889975.zip
/Reports/Current/DispatchIS_Reports/PUBLIC_DISPATCHIS_202206262300_0000000365890155.zip

How will I achieve this using NiFi? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `ExecuteScript` with Python as an engine and write custom logic to extract the required tags. Refer to this three-part cookbook: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922

Comment: not clear how exactly you want to extract. you could use ExtractText with regex like `href="([^"]+)"`

Comment: I have added the outputs